# Can I use an alias for static member function templates?

Tags: c++11

Using C++11, I'd like to call a static member function template without qualifying it with the scope of its enclosing class:

```
struct Test {
    template<typename T>
    static bool Function(T x)
    { /* ... */ }
};

int x;
Test::Function(x); // I don't want to write this
Function(x); // I want to be able to write this instead
```

I can define another function with the same signature at global scope and forward the arguments, but I'd prefer a solution that doesn't force me to write another function. I'd also like to avoid using a macro.

This question is related:
([using alias for static member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575700/using-alias-for-static-member-functions))
but doesn't seem to cover the case of function templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can alias the templated function if you want to do a little work with the `using` keyword first:

```
template<typename T>
using testfn = bool (*)(T);
```

and then create a pointer to the function with:

```
testfn<int> fnPointer = Test::Function;
```

and finally call it:

```
std::cout << boolalpha << fnPointer(x) << std::endl;
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/e3IGdD)

If you only ever want to bind to the case where `T` is `int`, you can do this:

```
using testfn = bool (*)(int);
//...
testfn fnPointer = Test::Function;
std::cout << boolalpha << fnPointer(x) << std::endl;
```

[Live Demo 2](http://ideone.com/8bo4Jt)

**Edit:** If you want a `constexpr` function pointer like in the accepted answer of the question you linked, that's a pretty simple extension:

```
constexpr auto yourFunction = &Test::Function<int>;
//...
std::cout << boolalpha << yourFunction(x) << std::endl;
```

[Live Demo 3](http://ideone.com/9RrP2I)

Comment: Your first method requires me to specialize for 'int'. That isn't really syntactically equivalent to a straight call to Test::Function

Comment: @Pris: I wasn't sure your exact use case, so I tried to be general with the first method, and more specific with the second.

Comment: In the simplest terms I want #define Function Test::Function without using a macro

Comment: @Pris: I'm not sure I follow. Are you looking for `constexpr` to appear somewhere?

Comment: Regarding your latest update to the answer: The problem is you're specializing Test::Function for int. The example I gave is just a simple example. I want a generic solution for a static template member function and the goal is to be able to call said method without the enclosing class scope resolution.

Comment: @Pris: I think I understand what you are saying. Basically you want that `using` on your `struct` for member function `Function` works essentially the same way as if your `struct` was instead a `namespace`. However, I don't believe that what you want is possible, given your constraints.

Comment: Thanks. This constexpr template function pointer worked for me (gotten from reading this): `template <typename T> constexpr auto GetParam = &mlpack::CLI::GetParam<T>;` .. then called with `bool sequential(GetParam<bool>("sequential"));`

Answer (score 0):

I learned this playing with the @andyg answer (probably above mine), but it worked for me and it doesn't require putting a different alias for every template.

It **requires c++14** or later though.

Step 1 - magical template alias:

```
template <typename T> constexpr auto funky1 = &Test::Function<T>;
```

Step 2 - lambda means you don't need to pass the template argument:

```
auto funky = [](auto in) { return funky1<decltype(in)>(in); };
```

[full example](https://ideone.com/WCviDs)

Also, inline full example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
  template <typename T> static bool Function(T x) { return true; }
};

// Magical template alias
template <typename T> constexpr auto funky1 = &Test::Function<T>;

// lambda means it'll infer the template parameters when calling
auto funky = [](auto in) { return funky1<decltype(in)>(in); };

int main() {
  int x = 0;

  // Just use the `funky1` version, but you have to specify the template parameters
  std::cout << "string: " << funky1<std::string>("I'm a string") << std::endl
            << "int: " << funky1<int>(42) << std::endl
            << "bool: " << funky1<bool>(true) << std::endl;

  // Use the `funky` version, where template parameters are inferred
  std::cout << "string: " << funky("I'm a string") << std::endl
            << "int: " << funky(42) << std::endl
            << "bool: " << funky(true) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```