# Any reason to declare constexpr for a function that returns void?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is what I read: [using alias for static member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575700/using-alias-for-static-member-functions)

In the answer I see a suggestion to use `constexpr`. What is the reason to use `constexpr` for `void` functions.

**Please demonstrate a simple use case. I am new to `constexpr` so in complex examples I will not understand the gist.**

Comment: FYI: Nothing in that question suggested making the function `constexpr`. It made the *member pointer* to that function a `constexpr`. This means that the function that variable references is available at compile-time.

Answer (score 6):

Rahul's answer cites the standard paragraph which allow `void` `constexpr` functions, but it doesn't give a use-case. One use-case that comes to my mind would be to have a `constexpr` class, and as usual factor out behavior common to method in helper methods. The standard explicitly mentions function doing checks, e.g. assertions. I don't have a concrete example at hand, but I can imagine something like

```
class A
{
public:
    constexpr X doSomething(Y arg1) {
        checkInvariant();
        constraintOnYArgument(arg1);
        // ...
        checkInvariant();        
    }

    constexpr X doSomethingElse(Y arg1) {
        checkInvariant();
        constraintOnYArgument(arg1);
        // ...
        checkInvariant();        
    }

private:
    constexpr void constraintOnYArguments(Y arg) {
    }

    constexpr void checkInvariant() {
        // some checks
        if (!some condition) {
            throw std::logic_error("Oh no!");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I think, this is the more useful answer. In particular, already in c++11 you can use `throw` inside a constexpr function.

Answer (score 2):

As per the C++ 14 standard, void is a literal type

> A type is a literal type if it is:
>
> — void; or
>
> — a scalar type; or
>
> — a reference type; or
>
> — an array of literal type; or
>
> — a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties: —
>   it has a trivial destructor,
>
> — it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one constexpr
>   constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move
>   constructor, and
>
> — all of its non-static data members and base classes are of
>   non-volatile literal types.

From [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3444.html):

> An arbitrary expression-statement is permitted, in order to allow
>   calls to functions performing checks and to allow assert-like
>   constructs. void also becomes a literal type, so that constexpr
>   functions which exist only to perform such checks may return void.

Comment: Please give a simple use case.

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable use case is the manipulation of **volatile** variables. The following is a **very** simplified case from embedded programming using GNU tools (g++, ld):

To make an address of a peripheral a `constexpr`, you need to put it at a fixed location. This must be done in a linker script:

```
⋮
/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
GPIO    0x48000000 (NOLOAD) : { *(.GPIO) }
⋮
```

Now, the `.GPIO` section is at the **fixed** address `0x48000400`. Peripherals can be modeled by PODs containing volatile members. In the following example, the POD is named `gpio_t` and has just a single member: `mode`. The member can be set up in a `constexpr` function. Of course, there is no benefit to use a function to set a variable to a constant value. But in real use cases values and addresses have to be calculated. Think, e.g., of setting a divider for a Baud rate.

```
struct gpio_t {
    volatile std::uint32_t mode;
   };

__attribute__ ((section (".GPIO"))) gpio_t Gpio = {0};

static constexpr gpio_t *port {&Gpio};

static constexpr void init () {
    port->mode = 42u;
   };

void main {
    init ();
    ⋮
};
```

Note: The C-style idiom of casting integers to addresses does not work because it `reinterpret_cast<>` does not qualify for creating `constexpr` pointers (see [Since C++14 illegal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200827/getting-around-the-reinterpret-cast-limitation-with-constexpr)). The following **fails**:

```
constexpr gpio_t *port {(gpio_t *) 0x48000400};
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as parameter number is an integral constant, this constexpr version will compute the result at compile-time (C++11 compilers only). And when the number is a run-time integer, this same function is perfectly capable of computing the result at run-time. So you don't need two different versions of the same program: one for compile-time and another for run-time. One implementation does it all.

Comment: A function returning void usually doesn't compute a result (unless you coun't throwing an exception)