# Alias the definition of a static member from a private sub-struct

Tags: c++, static, private, using

#### Background

I have a `private` data structure buried within many nested namespaces & classes as shown in the (simplified) example below. The `private` structure contains numerous `static const` members (lengthy STL containers, mostly), represented in this example by a single `static const int i`.

*Note: the presence of the `const` here doesn't seem to bear on my problem; it's included merely for the sake of completeness.*

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

namespace foo {
    namespace bar {
        class MyClass {
            struct Data {
                static const int i;
                // ... + many more
            };
        public:
            int Get() const { return Data::i; }
        };  
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const int foo::bar::MyClass::Data::i = 42;  // [A] <- Verbose; but works fine
// ... + many more                          // [A]

//using concise = foo::bar::MyClass::Data;  // [B] <- Nope; 'Data' is private
//const int concise::i = 42;                // [B] <- Ideally
//// ... + many more                        // [B]
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    cout << foo::bar::MyClass{}.Get() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Need

Defining static members such as `i` outside of their data structure is trivial (see `[A]`). However, as the number of namespaces/classes/structs in a member's hierarchy grows, it becomes desirable **to abbreviate the hierarchy** (chain/tree/prefix*?*) **in the member's definition for the sake of readability**.
Imagine something like the following was required, many times over:

```
const std::vector<std::string> foo::bar::baz::MyClass::MySubClass::MySubSubClass::PrivateDataStruct::vecOfStr = {…};
```

At some point, for the coder's sanity, they would want to shorten the syntax of this operation.

---

#### Problem

My naive attempt (see `[B]`) at **aliasing the definition of `i` via the `using` directive has not worked** as expected **due to the `Data` structure being `private`**. Swapping code block `[B]` for `[A]` yields (*in VS2017*):

> error C2248: 'foo::bar::MyClass::Data': cannot access private struct declared in class 'foo::bar::MyClass'

*Ideone* (gcc?) results in a similar error at `[B]`:

> error: ‘struct foo::bar::MyClass::Data’ is private within this context

---

#### Question(s)

1. **Why doesn't `[B]` work**, while `[A]` does?
2. How might I **define `i` with its hierarchy chain/tree/prefix aliased** (preferably via `using`)?
3. **Bonus:** What is the preferred nomenclature for what I've been calling the namespace/class/structure hierarchy chain/tree/prefix when referencing a member?

---

Other questions (such as [using alias for static member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575700/using-alias-for-static-member-functions)) hew closely to mine, but don't seem to pertain.

Please feel free to improve this question with any edits or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't [B] work, while [A] does?

`private` stuff (class/member name) can only be used at several places, including definitions (which is [A]) but not aliases (in scope not allowed to use types)

> How might I define `i` with its hierarchy chain/tree/prefix aliased (preferably via using)?
>   Bonus: What is the preferred nomenclature for what I've been calling the namespace/class/structure hierarchy chain/tree/prefix when referencing a member?

You might still shorten the namespace part:

```
 using namespace foo::bar;
 const int MyClass::Data::i = 42;
```

And for the class part, you can still add some using in parent class, if acceptable:

```
class MyClass {
    class MySubClass{
        friend class MyClass;
        class MySubSubClass{
            friend class MyClass;
            class PrivateDataStruct {
                static const std::vector<std::string> vecOfStr;
                // ...
            };
            // ...
        };
        // ...
    };
    using inner = MySubClass::MySubSubClass::PrivateDataStruct;
public:
    // ...
};
```

And finally:

```
const std::vector<std::string>
foo::bar::baz::MyClass::MySubClass::MySubSubClass::PrivateDataStruct::vecOfStr = {/*…*/};
```

becomes:

```
using namespace foo::bar::baz;

const std::vector<std::string> MyClass::inner::vecOfStr = {/*…*/};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41565f9ec8a25774)

Comment: I like the approach of `using inner =` within the class structure (nice!), however that alias is itself `private` & thus results in the same errors. Making that `inner` alias `public` seems to work, but does that expose my private parts?

Comment: @quasinormalized: Demo added. `inner` might (and should, to keep initial intend) be private. but indeed, whole path should be accessible for `MyClass` to construct the alias.

Comment: I see how this is the answer to what, I now realize, was my overly reductive question. In my attempt to simplify my problem for SO, I omitted the fact that there was a PIMPL amongst my privates. E.g.: `MyClass` would be the interface and `MySubClass` the PIMPL'd implementation. Hence, `using inner = MySubClass::…` complains about `MySubClass` being an incomplete type. Any further insight you (or anyone) has would be most welcome; otherwise, I'll accept this answer & just live with my unsightly, long definitions. Any ideas? I can make that a new question if appropriate.

Comment: So you might do the `inner` from the pimpl class. Which reduces length less than from main class (a at definition place, you will have definition of full classes).